# How do I save an entity collection to the database using RIA Services and Entity Framework? 

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0

I'm able to add to the collection in the view model, on method to add to the collection and on to submit the changes:

```
    public void AddEntityDetail()
    {
        this.IsBusy = true;
            this.entityContext.SubmitChanges(OnSubmitChangesCompleted, null);
    }

    public void AddEntityCollection(EntityDetail entityDetail)
    {
        if (!this.entityDetailContext.EntityDetails.Contains(entityDetail))
            this.entityDetailContext.EntityDetails.Add(entityDetail);

    }
```

I currently don't know how to pass this though the service and add it to the database.
Also this entity is not bound to the xaml.

Comment: You are not required to pass anything to service. SubmitChanges method do that. Binding itself or binding in xaml also do not affect anything.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of WCF RIA Services is that it hides the data transport for you.

You just do CRUD operations on the datasets and call `SubmitChanges()`. SubmitChanges creates a changeset (literally a set of changes made) and transports them to the server.

The server side calls the various RIA Servers CRUD methods, for each object type, by calling methods in order until all changes are processed. Methods are matched by parameters and return types.

To paraphrase my previous answer:

```
On the receiving side it goes through all the changes and says:

Q. "Is this an object deletion?"
A. Yes...
Q. "What object type is it?"
A. BlahBlah 
Q. "Do we have a method called Delete that takes a BlahBlah parameter?"
A. Yes...
It then calls that method with the object from the changeset

Rinse and repeat for all other changes.
```